# Export mysql schema (data only) except for one table

Tags: mysql, database, export

I have a script to export the schema of my MySQL database based on which I can generate my migrations. For this process I only require the database schema, not the data itself. This is what I currently use:

```
mysqldump -u root --p[pass] -h localhost mydb_prod --add-drop-table --no-data > mydb_prod-`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`.sql
```

The `--no-data` option does the trick.

However, my migrations history is also kept in a database table. This means that I do want to export the data for my `migrations` table. I know about the `--ignore-table` option to explicitly ignore specific tables, however, this would mean that I would have to explicitly list all of my tables which might lead to problems in the future since we only do migrations every once in a while.

Is there a way to export the schema of the database without table data except one (or multiple) explicitly specified tables?

Comment: Fairly certain the only way to do this is use `--ignore-table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions but I found a workaround so I might as well share it.

I basically first export the schema of all tables without the data and then I export just my single migrations table with the data and append this to my .sql output file:

```
#/bin/bash

now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)
output_file="mydb_prod-$now.sql"

mysqldump -u root -p[pass] -h localhost mydb_prod --add-drop-table --no-data > "$output_file"
mysqldump -u root -p[pass] -h localhost mydb_prod migration_table --add-drop-table >> "$output_file"
```

This gives me exactly what I need without having to manually specify every single table explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script to edit out whatever table from the dump file itself.  I sometimes use `sed` to rename tables, etc.